# Why is PKCS used?

Tags: rsa, pkcs11, pkcs12, pkcs7, pkcs1

Can anybody help me in understanding why PKCS is used? My confusion is that whether PKCS is used to transfer key in between client and server OR it is a standard to encrypt and decrypt the payload.

I know I am asking some basic question But I am new to this security space and I don't want my basic itself to be wrong that's why I am asking this.

Comment: All right then. So as the name suggests, we are talking about a set of standards, the description of each of them is on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS

Answer (score 1):

PKCS (Public-Key Cryptography Standards) is a set of standards by RSA Security.
It has many standards and each of those defining set of protocols, here are some of them:

- RSA private and public keys for encryption, decryption, signing, and signature verification
- Protocol for a shared key exchange over an insecure channel
- Certificate request, extensions, etc
- Protocol for carrying certificate private keys
- etc

> My confusion is that whether PKCS is used to transfer key in between client and server OR it is a standard to encrypt and decrypt the payload.

As you can see, there are plenty of usages for PKCS, I encourage you to read about PKI and these standards and other related concepts in-depth:

- [Public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
- [PKCS set of standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)
- [X509 certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509)
- [Key-agreement protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol)
- [Public key infrastructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure)
- [Digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)